# preg_replace regex to remove stray end tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string containing different types of html tags and stuff, including some `<img>` elements. I am trying to wrap those `<img>` elements inside a `<figure>` tag. So far so good using a preg_replace like this:

```
preg_replace( '/(<img.*?>)/s','<figure>$1</figure>',$content);
```

However, if the `<img>`tag has a neighboring `<figcaption>` tag, the result is rather ugly, and produces a stray end tag for the figure-element:

```
<figure id="attachment_9615">
<img class="size-full" src="http://www.example.com/pic.png" alt="name" width="1699" height="354" />
<figcaption class="caption-text"></figure>Caption title here</figcaption>
</figure>
```

I've tried a whole bunch of preg_replace regex variations to wrap both the img-tag and figcaption-tag inside figure, but can't seem to make it work.

My latest try:

```
preg_replace( '/(<img.*?>)(<figcaption .*>*.<\/figcaption>)?/s',
'<figure">$1$2</figure>',
$content);
```

Comment: [why, oh why with regex, it never stops...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: May I suggest *not* using a RegEx for this task?  Have you considered a DOM parser?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Well, sure. If you know another way to do this in Wordpress, with the purpose of cleaning up the RSS feed output for FB Instant Articles. I could probably remove some Wordpress content filters, and redo all of them, but wouldn't a regex be ...easier?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thanks, I'll do some reading!

Comment: I don't see how you're getting that result.`<img.*?>` shouldn't match the `figcaption`.

Comment: @ThomasL.G It looks like you messed with `.*>*.` in the figcaption, how about [something like this](https://regex101.com/r/iM4oX6/3) and replace by `<figure>$0</figure>`. Please show input sample that fails and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others pointed out, better use a parser, i.e. `DOMDocument` instead. The following code wraps a `<figure>` tag around each `img` where the next sibling is a `<figcaption>`:

```
<?php

$html = <<<EOF
<html>
    <img class="size-full" src="http://www.example.com/pic.png" alt="name" width="1699" height="354" />
    <figcaption class="caption-text">Caption title here</figcaption>

    <img class="size-full" src="http://www.example.com/pic.png" alt="name" width="1699" height="354" />

    <img class="size-full" src="http://www.example.com/pic.png" alt="name" width="1699" height="354" />
    <figcaption class="caption-text">Caption title here</figcaption>
</html>
EOF;

$dom = new DOMdocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

# get all images
$imgs = $xpath->query("//img");

foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    if ($img->nextSibling->tagName == 'figcaption') {

        # create a new figure tag and append the cloned elements
        $figure = $dom->createElement('figure');
        $figure->appendChild($img->cloneNode(true));
        $figure->appendChild($img->nextSibling->cloneNode(true));

        # insert the newly generated elements right before $img
        $img->parentNode->insertBefore($figure, $img);

        # and remove both the figcaption and the image from the DOM
        $img->nextSibling->parentNode->removeChild($img->nextSibling);
        $img->parentNode->removeChild($img);

    }
}
$dom->formatOutput=true;
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/ivzuZT).

To have a `<figure>` tag around ***all*** your images, you might want to add an `else` branch:

```
} else {
    $figure = $dom->createElement('figure');
    $figure->appendChild($img->cloneNode(true));
    $img->parentNode->insertBefore($figure, $img);

    $img->parentNode->removeChild($img);
}
```